# Getting all elements while using group by on string column using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, datarow

I want to group by datatable using followng method. However i can not select a column which includes string.

dtTAConvert example;

```
SAMPLE_TIME  WAIT_CLASS 
23:11:12     CPU
23:11:12     IO
23:11:12     IO
23:11:11     CPU
23:11:11     CPU
```

What i want is this;

```
SAMPLE_TIME  WAIT_CLASS COUNT
23:11:12     CPU        1
23:11:12     IO         2
23:11:11     CPU        2
```

So far, i wrote below code;

```
var dtTAConvertList =
    (from dr1 in dtTAConvert.AsEnumerable()
     group dr1 by dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") into g
     select new
     {
         SAMPLE_TIME = g.Key,
         WAIT_CLASS = g.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS"),          // ==> I get error in this line
         COUNT = Math.Round(g.Sum(h => h.Field<double>("COUNT")) / 15.0, 2),
     });
```

It throws the exception

'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow, string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'

If i change above code to like below, it works;

```
WAIT_CLASS = g.First().Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS"),
```

However this returns only the first element, which is not work for me.

How can i select string column like as i explained?

Comment: in your expected output it seems you want to group by both `SAMPLE_TIME` and `WAIT_CLASS` but you're not doing this in your query. any reasoning?

Comment: @Aomine well, i was not know that. I am really bad at linQ. How can i group both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving the said error because as shown [`IGrouping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) i.e. *a collection of objects that have a common key* does not contain a definition for 'Field'. you probably expected this to be a `DataRow`.

In addition, currently you're grouping only by `SAMPLE_TIME` which is not what you need, rather you need to group by both `SAMPLE_TIME` and  `WAIT_CLASS` to get the aforementioned result.

Here's how to group by both of those fields via query syntax:

```
var result = from dr in dtTAConvert.AsEnumerable()
             group dr by new 
             {
                  sampleTime = dr.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
                  waitClass = dr.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS")
             } into g
             select new
             {
                  SampleTime = g.Key.sampleTime,
                  WaitClass = g.Key.waitClass,
                  Count = g.Count()
             });
```

or fluent syntax:

```
var result = dtTAConvert.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(dr => new
                {
                    sampleTime = dr.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
                    waitClass = dr.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS")
                }).Select(g => new
                {
                    SampleTime = g.Key.sampleTime,
                    WaitClass = g.Key.waitClass,
                    Count = g.Count()
                });
```